# JQuery Datatable moving the pagination to the top

Tags: jquery, jquery-pagination

I am trying to move the pagination property to the upper right hand side of the table. I understand that I have to use the dom property.

```
 $(document).ready( function () {   
    $('#myTbl').dataTable({   
        "bInfo":true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
         "bPaginate" : true,
         "aLengthMenu": [[50,100,150,200,250,300,-1], [50,100,150,200,250,300,"All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "dom": '<"top"flp>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">'           

    });
});
```

I thought by using flp on top would make those options appear on top, however the pagination appears on the bottom of the table. Would appreciae any help in understanding this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you're using the old API (<= 1.9.x) you need to make sure that you use the hungarian notation for `dom`, it's a string so it is `sDom`.

```
$('#myTbl').dataTable({   
    "bInfo":true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bPaginate" : true,
    "aLengthMenu": [[50,100,150,200,250,300,-1], [50,100,150,200,250,300,"All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": '<"top"flp>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

put in css ``.dataTables_wrapper .pagination {
float: left !important;
}`

also add `

```
   $('#tableid').dataTable({       
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "ordering": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "searching": false,
        "info": false,
        "dom": '<bottam>p',  (this line only)
    });`
```

Comment: Isn't `bottam` a typo?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the [dom option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) has a great example.

`L`ength and `f`ilter above `<` the `t`able; `i`nformation and `p`agination below table:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "dom": '<lf<t>ip>'
} );
```

The tricks are knowing about this crazy dom option and knowing what the heck `lftrip` means.